# Access android lock code for two way authentication

Tags: android, basic-authentication

I was wondering if there is any API which helps us access the lock code for your phone from your code. I was basically trying to use it to provide two way authentication for my application. But couldn't come across any.

I know ways where you can figure out if the phone is locked using pattern lock or pin or stuff like that. But I want to know if we could actually access these codes and use them as a way of authentication in our code

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to know if we could actually access these codes and use them as a way of authentication in our code

No. That would be really bad if you could read that data